# Read a file via argparse and print the file contents line by line

Tags: python, json, list

I want to

Code:

```
import argparse

import csv

import os

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description = "Parse the json file")

parser.add_argument("-f", help="file to upload")

args = parser.parse_args()

fileName = args.f

with open(filename, 'rb') as f:

    try:
        for lines in f:
        print(lines)


    except:
        print("The file " + fileName + " could not be opened.")
```

I cannot get the file lines to print out and the exception to run if the file is incorrect.

Comment: Please format  your code properly

Answer (score 0):

Why are you opening in binary mode?  Also, your try/catch is in the wrong place

```
try:
    with open(filename) as f:
        for line in f:
            print(line)
except:
    print('The file ' + filename + ' could not be opened.')
```